# I'm generating an XML using DOM in demo1.jsp which is running on server 1 and want to send that XML file to demo2.jsp which is running on server 2

Tags: java, xml, jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : demo1
    Created on : Jun 30, 2016, 5:00:56 PM
    Author     : Aman Aslam
--%>
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Timer"%>
<%@page import="java.util.TimerTask"%>
<%@page import="org.w3c.dom.Node"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.Transformer"%>
<%@page import="org.w3c.dom.Element"%>
<%@page import="org.w3c.dom.Document"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.TransformerException"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>xml generation</title>
    </head>
    <body> 

 <%!
            public void jdbcdom() throws SQLException, ParserConfigurationException, TransformerConfigurationException, TransformerException{
           String id, name, age, city, country, temp;
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");}
catch(Exception e){ e.toString(); }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nic", "root", "jumanjis");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from abc");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.newDocument();
        Element root = doc.createElement("root");
        doc.appendChild(root);

        while(rs.next()){
            id=rs.getString("id");
            name=rs.getString("name");
            age=rs.getString("age");
            city=rs.getString("city");
            country=rs.getString("country");
            root.appendChild(getEmployee(doc, id, name, age, city, country));

        }
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);

            StreamResult file = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\Aman Aslam\\Desktop\\NIC\\xml\\abc.xml"));
             transformer.transform(source, file);
}

public static Node getEmployee(Document doc, String id, String name, String age, String city, String country){
        Element employee =doc.createElement("employee");
        employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc, employee, "id", id));
        employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc, employee, "name", name));
        employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc, employee, "age", age));
        employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc, employee, "city", city));
        employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(doc, employee, "country", country));
        return employee;
    }

     public static  Node getEmployeeElements(Document doc, Element element, String name, String value){
        Element node = doc.createElement(name);
        node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
        return node;
     }
class Scheduler extends TimerTask{
public void run(){
try{
jdbcdom();
}catch(Exception f){ f.toString(); }
}        
}
            %>

        <%
            Timer timer=new Timer();
            Calendar date=Calendar.getInstance();
            date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);
            date.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
            date.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 56);
            date.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Scheduler(), date.getTime(),86400);



            %>

    </body>
</html>
```

above is the demo1.jsp in which I use DOM to create and xml file abc.xml

```
<%-- 
    Document   : demo2
    Created on : Jun 30, 2016, 7:00:24 PM
    Author     : Aman Aslam
--%>
<%@page import="org.w3c.dom.NodeList"%>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@page import="org.xml.sax.SAXException"%>
<%@page import="org.w3c.dom.Node"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult"%>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.Transformer"%>
<%@page import="org.w3c.dom.Element"%>
<%@page import="org.w3c.dom.Document"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.TransformerException"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException"%>
<%@page import="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>DB store</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%!
    public void xmlread() throws SAXException, IOException, SQLException, ParserConfigurationException{
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse("C:\\Users\\Aman Aslam\\Desktop\\NIC\\xml\\abc.xml");
        String name, city, country;
        int id, age;
        name="";
        city="";
        country="";
        id=0;
        age=0;


try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");}
catch(Exception e){ e.toString(); }
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nic", "root", "jumanjis");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        try{
        st.executeUpdate("create table xyz(id int, name varchar(15), age int, city varchar(20), country varchar(20))");
         } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("table xyz already exist. Only copying new items");
        }
        NodeList employeelist = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
        for(int i=0; i<employeelist.getLength();i++){
            Node n = employeelist.item(i);
            if(n.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element employee = (Element) n;
                NodeList childnodes = employee.getChildNodes();

                for(int j=0;j<childnodes.getLength();j++){
                    Node child = childnodes.item(j);
                    if(child.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                        Element x = (Element) child;

                        if(x.getTagName().equals("id"))
                           id = Integer.parseInt(x.getTextContent());
                        else if(x.getTagName().equals("name"))
                            name = x.getTextContent();
                        else if(x.getTagName().equals("age"))
                            age = Integer.parseInt(x.getTextContent());
                        else if(x.getTagName().equals("city"))
                            city = x.getTextContent();
                        else if(x.getTagName().equals("country"))
                            country = x.getTextContent();

                    }

                }
                st.executeUpdate("insert into xyz values("+id+", '"+name+"', "+age+", '"+city+"', '"+country+"')");

            }
        }
}


            %>

            <%
                xmlread();
                %>
                <h1>Db copied</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is demo2.jsp in which i read abc.xml and create its table.

I want abc.xml to be sent directly to demo2.jsp from demo1.jsp.
What methods can I use here to do it?

Comment: Which JSP must be invoked from the web browser? demo1 or demo2?

Comment: Hummm... I reply myself after reading `demo1.jsp`: If I'm not wrong, this JSP periodically saves `abc.xml`. Then, from another server, `demo2.jsp` is invoked asynchronously, and it must access the later `abc.xml`. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes exactly what I want. But I am unable to send the xml from demo1 to demo 2. Actually, I'm doing this project in an internship and my boss asked me to implement it using JSP.

Comment: @LittleSanti Your answer really solves it all. Thanks.

Comment: Fine, but a little upvote wouldn't harm me either... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to have a background function saving periodically `abc.xml` in one server and make it public to the asynchronous calls from another server (intended for demo2.jsp).

In the first place, a JSP is not the rightest way to implement a periodic program, because a JSP is expected to produce a *user output*. A background program, instead, does not produce an immediate output at all.

I suggest you to make it like this:

1. Extract your `jdbcdom` method to a new singleton class.
2. Replace your `demo1.jsp` by a servlet:

   - Fill in the `init` method with the TimerTask managing.
   - Program it as auto-startable through this annotation: [@WebServlet(loadOnStartup=1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html).
3. Create a new JSP `readAbc.jsp` to *publish* the `abc.xml` file and deploy it to server 1. This JSP should read this file and produce an XML output (not HTML).
4. Modify your `demo2.jsp`: Replace the absolute path to `abc.xml` by a call to `readAbc.jsp` through `new URL(...).openStream()`: The returned stream is what you should parse as XML.

(Not sure if you will have any concurrency problems between the servlet and the readAbc.jsp when trying to access the same file at the same time.)